# Logic problem is making me so confused....

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can you help me out? It's been quite a pain in the backseat lately.

> Question: Let $A$ be any set with $|A|=m$. Find $|\{x\in P(A):|x|\le 1\}|$ (where $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$).

Hope you will find time to answer this!

Comment: How can an element of the power set be compared to 1 ?

Comment: Think about what $|x| \le 1$ means.  What does $|x| = 0$ mean?  What does $|x| = 1$ mean?  If $x \in P(A)$ then $x$ is a set.  $x$ is a subset of $A$.  If $|x|=1$ what elements of A can belong in $x$.  How many possible different subsets are there so that $|x| = 1$?  That $|x| = 0$?

Answer (score 2):

How many distinct subsets with one element can you find in a set with $m$ elements? How many with less than one element (that is, no element)?

For the first subquestion, try first with $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and make a conjecture. The second subquestion should be easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :). I appreciate that you took time to give an answer! May you continue to share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

$\{x \in P(A): |x| \le 1\}=$

$\{x \subset A| x$ has $0$ or $1$ elements$\}=$

$\{x|x = \{a\}$ for some $a \in A$ or $x = \emptyset\}$

Meanwhile....

$|A| = m$ means $A = \{a_1, a_2,......, a_m\}$ for some distinct $a_i$ elements.  There are $m$ of these elements.

So $\{x|x = \{a\}$ for some $a \in A$ or $x = \emptyset\}=$

$\{\emptyset, \{a_1\}, \{a_2\},......,\{a_m\}\}$

What is $|\{\emptyset, \{a_1\}, \{a_2\},......,\{a_m\}\}|$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :). I appreciate that you took time to give an answer! May you continue to share your knowledge.